# Why aren't we using digital signatures for the DHCP?

Tags: dhcp, security

Why aren't we using digital signatures for the DHCP in order to stop Rouge DHCP attacks?

Comment: DHCP snooping, dynamic ARP inspection, etc. are easy enough to implement, and you get the benefit of other protections, too.

Comment: With DHCP clients should not need to know anything about the DHCP server. Combining that feature with how validation of digital signatures works is very hard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the risk of a DHCP attack doesn’t outweigh the complexity of implementing digital signatures.